# Convolution with different kernel for each pixel

Tags: python, pytorch

For example, I have a tensor

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and I have some kernels

```
k = torch.tensor([[0, 0.4, 0.6], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6], [0.9, 0.05, 0]])
```

I want to do the convolution of `x` but kernels (`k`) are different for each element of `x`. The answer should be:

```
y = torch.tensor([1.6, 2.5, 1.95])
```

I get this answer in such a way:

```
1.6 = 0 * 0 + 1 * 0.4 + 2 * 0.6
2.5 = 1 * 0.1 + 2 * 0.3 + 3 * 0.6
```

I can do the simple for-loop but it's very inefficient.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could state your question.